# What is the "WWJD" standard for?

Tags: meaning

I often see some young people wearing bracelets with 4 letters "WWJD".

So, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[What Would Jesus Do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_would_Jesus_do%3F)"

It's a Christian religious insignia.